# using App_Data in connection string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sqlite

simple stuff, I want to use App_Data as my db storage folder.

**How can I reference App_Data in my connString.**

```
<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=mydb.sqlite; ..." />
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
<add name="ConnectionString" 
connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\MyDb.sqlite;......" />
```

The `|DataDirectory|` token would expand to an `App_Data` folder under the root of a web application.